# Regex PHP preg_match priority

Tags: php, regex

I have this code

```
if (preg_match('/J[a-zA-Z0-9]+S/', $id)) {  
    echo "1";
}
else if (preg_match('/BUT[a-zA-Z0-9]+TN/', $id)) {  
    echo "2";
}
```

I have the `id` as `BUTEqHLHxJSRr9DJZSMTN`, Instead of getting `2` as output, I am getting `1`.
This is has BUTEqHLHx`JSRr9DJZS`MTN which is making it match with the first expression. But this exp also has BUT/TN and it should also match with that regex also right?

Is there any way I can make the regex pattern in such a way that it do not check for matches from the middle of an expression, but rather it should match the beginning and end.

I don't know whether this is a stupid question to ask,but is there anyway its possible to prevent pregmatch to match from the begining?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `^` (beginning of string), `$` (end of string) anchors to match an entire string.
For example, this will give you the result of `2` seeing how it matches the entire string from start to end.

```
$id = 'BUTEqHLHxJSRr9DJZSMTN';

if (preg_match('/^J[a-zA-Z0-9]+S$/', $id)) { echo "1"; }
else if(preg_match('/^BUT[a-zA-Z0-9]+TN$/', $id)) { echo "2"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundaries to avoid matching unwanted text:

```
if(preg_match('/\bJ[a-zA-Z0-9]+S\b/', $id)) { 
    echo "1";
}
else if(preg_match('/\bBUT[a-zA-Z0-9]+TN\b/', $id)) {   
    echo "2";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try `^` then it will check must be start from given string

```
   if(preg_match('/^J[a-zA-Z0-9]+S/', $id)) { 
        echo "1";
   }
   else if(preg_match('/^BUT[a-zA-Z0-9]+TN/', $id)) {   
        echo "2";
   }
```